# Java, count rows in azure database table

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to count the number of rows in an Azure database table and display that number on my android app. I have read Azure's documentation on retrieving data from tables here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#querying

But it doesn't mention a built-in COUNT function. Does the Azure library have a COUNT function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AlexChen-Wx said, you can use the method **`includeTotalCount`** of Object `MobileServiceTable` on the JavaScript backend of Azure Mobile Service to count the number of records.

If you want to directly count on the Android App, you can try to use the method **`includeInlineCount`** of Class `MobileServiceTable` in Java, please see the source code at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/android/src/sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/table/MobileServiceTable.java#L349.

Comment: Using this? final MobileServiceList<Crime> result = mToDoTable.includeInlineCount().execute().get();

Comment: @Cian Yeah, please try.

Comment: It did not work, nor did: final MobileServiceList<Crime> result = mToDoTable.where().includeInlineCount().execute().get();

Comment: @Cian Try to code `int count = result.getTotalCount()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is a method called `includeTotalCount` which will return the count of all records. For details, pls reference article [MobileServiceTable Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554239.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean loop = true;
 int totalrows = 0;
 int skipnumber = 0;
 int rows=0;
 while(loop) {
     int count = mToDoTable.select().skip(skipnumber).execute().get().size();
     skipnumber = skipnumber+50;
     rows = rows+count;
     if(rows<skipnumber){
           loop=false;
           totalrows = rows;
           Log.i("count",String.valueOf(totalrows));

     }
}
```